# How to use mod_rewrite without clashing with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

So I have Wordpress installed, let's call the domain test.com.  The .htaccess that wordpress created in the default directory (the one that is one level above wp-content) is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want to add another rule, which if triggered, should case Wordpress to not rewrite.  So for instance, suppose I want test.com/nochange to redirect to test.com/script.php, instead of doing the normal Wordpress redirects.  Normally the .htaccess for this would be

```
RewriteRule ^nochange$ ./script.php [NC,L]
```

But what happens is that Wordpress ends up running anyways, and of course a 404 not found occurs.  If I removed the Wordpress .htaccess components, everything works.  What do I do to get them to work together?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just needed to use the END tag.